# Is There a Method That Calls the "Done" key on the Keyboard?

Tags: android, keyboard

Hello  Hopefully my question is fairly self explanatory.

But to elaborate, I want to be able to tell my program that the done key was pressed even if it wasn't. Hopefully this is just a line of two of code.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by adding a OnKeyListener to your EditText, here is the code snippet:

```
myEditText.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
                    // The "done" key is pressed, handle the event here.
                }
                return false;
            }

        });
```

You can also achieve this by setting a OnEditorActionListener to your EditText. here is the code:

```
myEditText.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
myEditText.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView arg0, int keycode, KeyEvent event) {
                if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
                // The "done" key is pressed, handle the event here.
               }
       return false;
    }

});
```

Comment: I think this answer misses the point of my question. This code allows me to handle what happens wen the done of enter key is pressed. What i need to do is "trick" the program into thinking that the done key was pressed even if it wasn't. However this answer was helpful as it gave me an id that I will be able to try later on.